# How to assign multiple listbox values to one variable and put those in Email "TO" field

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, excel-2010, outlook-2010

I am trying to be able to select multiple values in two listboxes and assign to two separate variables. I want to then take those variables containing the selections and generate an email with the variable contents populating the "TO" field in an outlook email. Right now I am getting a Run-Time Error 94 - Invalid Use of Null.

Thanks for all your help!

```
Dim EAddress, MAddress As String

Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Emailfrm.EmpEmaillb.RowSource = "Searched_Employee_Email"
Emailfrm.ManagerEmaillb.RowSource = "Searched_Manager_Email"

End Sub

Public Sub Email_Click()
Dim OLobjMsg, NewMsg As Object

    EAddress = Emailfrm.EmpEmaillb.Value
    MAddress = Emailfrm.ManagerEmaillb.Value

    Set objMsg = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    objMsg.Session.Logon
    Set NewMsg = objMsg.CreateItem(0)

    With NewMsg
        .To = EAddress & MAddress
        .Subject = "BT Employee Database Inquiry Email"
        '.Body = "Have a great weekend!"
    End With

    Unload Me

    NewMsg.Display
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asuming that your listboxes contain valid email addresses, I propose to

- define `ListBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti`
- select multiple mail addresses by using Ctrl-Click
- concatenate all selected addresses from the Listbox into one single string, e.g.

_

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim LBCnt As Integer, AllAddr As String

    AllAddr = ""

    For LBCnt = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1

        If ListBox1.Selected(LBCnt) Then
            If AllAddr = "" Then
                AllAddr = ListBox1.List(LBCnt)
            Else
                AllAddr = AllAddr & ";" & ListBox1.List(LBCnt)
            End If
        End If
    Next LBCnt
    Debug.Print AllAddr

End Sub
```

- repeat for the 2nd listbox ...